# Css height 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I have the following html:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

and css:

```
html,body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}

#page {
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:500px;
}

#header {
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
}

#content {
   width:500px;
   height:100%;
}
```

The problem is that content div is the height of the window + the height of the header.
How can i make it to be the height of the window - the height of the header, I mean to stretch horizontally all over the remaining window. ??

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3nC7Y/3/ - @user2361682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't need to support IE7 and below - you can use a useful trick with

```
position: absolute
```

for #header and

```
padding-top: 100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

for #content.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jx4sC/2/

Details regarding box-sizing support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) in modern browsers and let the browser calculate the height of your content box:

```
#content {
   width:500px;
   height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Similarly you could use some JavaScript to do the same. But then make sure to update your calculations each time the browser height gets changed.

Comment: I would prefer a method that works for non-modern browsers too :)

Comment: @user2361682 Then you might either search for a polyfill or code something similar in JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is supprisingly hacky to get going and you may not have to do it. for example, say you wanted to give #content a background-color, put it on #page instead.

```
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
  /* body should have height:100% by default */
}

#page {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:500px;
  /* use page as you would have used #content*/
}

#header {
  height:100px;
}

#content {

}
```

edit: but if you really need to do this, [you can do it like so](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

```
#page {
   position: relative;
}
#content{
   position: absolute; 
   top: 100px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

this is not ideal because if you wanted to make #header bigger you need to remember to update #content, you can no longer use the normal page layout